# ViewData["key"] not available when using RedirectToRoute("Route") in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, viewdata

I am working over my first application over MVC3 and still kind of a newbie in it.
Problem is am putting some message in my controller in ViewData dictionary to be shown over the viewpage, but as far as I am using return View("Index"); the meesage is received in view correctly but when I change controller to return through RedirectToRoute("Default").. the ViewData[] dictionary displays null value.

I want to use RedirectToRoute("Default") to change the url address .. Is there any way I can also use ViewData[] with RedirectToRoute("Default")?

```
public ActionResult Logout()
    {
        Session.Contents.Remove("usrnme");
        Session.Contents.Remove("usrId");
        ViewData["mainMessage"] = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.";
        //return View("Index");
        return RedirectToRoute("Default");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
TempData["mainMessage"] = ....
```

and in Default

```
if (TempData["mainMessage"] != null) 
{    
    ViewData["mainMessage"] = TempData["mainMessage"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no "view" being returned on this action (Seems like your logout method is not on whichever controller handles the "Default" route), you can't assign the ViewData to it.  Instead, set the ViewData in the Action of the Controller that is mapped to the "Default" route.